# How to bulk change JSON format for Elastic Search

Tags: json, elasticsearch, jq, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I have the below format and was hoping to pre-process in bulk using elasticsearch.

```
{"title":"April","url":"https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/April", "abstract":"April is the 4th month of the year, and comes between March and May. It is one of four months to have 30 days.","sections":["The Month","April in poetry","Events in April","Fixed Events","Moveable Events","Selection of Historical Events","Trivia","References"]}
{"title":"August","url":"https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/August", "abstract":"August (Aug.) is the 8th month of the year in the Gregorian calendar, coming between July and September.","sections":["The Month","August observances","Fixed observances and events","Moveable and Monthlong events","Selection of Historical Events","Trivia","References"]}
```

I am trying to add the index,type line before each of my line.

```
{"index":{"_index":"myindex","_type":"wiki","_id":"1"}}
```

On reading prior posts I am using [Kevin Marsh's post](http://kevinmarsh.com/2014/10/23/using-jq-to-import-json-into-elasticsearch.html) like below:

```
cat file.json jq -c '.[] | {"index": {"_index": "myindex", "_type": "wiki", "_id": .id}}, .'
```

I am not using the pipe as I am trying to figure out the error that precedes that.I get an error jq:no such file or directory. I then used `jq --version and get jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you need.

Comment: Thanks Hatim , was hoping to find if there is a issue in my cat statement or a better solution to change the format to be ready for bulk api using elastic search.

Comment: As per my understanding, you have a json file and you want to index it in Elasticsearch using Bulk API. Right?

Comment: Yes Hatim and its over 10000 lines like above and I would like to pre proess the file by addin {"index":{"_index":"myindex","_type":"wiki","_id":"1"}} before each object in the json file.

Comment: You need to format your question correctly, it is very unorganized

Comment: I have done the formatting of the question @Ibo.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. This worked for me. Let me know if this helps.

```
cat data.json | jq -c '. | {"index": {"_index": "json", "_type": "json"}}, .'  | curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @-
```

Learn more about [jq : a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Comment: Will absolutely format going forward. Sorry about that. Hatim used the below command in the format you gave:

Comment: cat data.json | jq -c '. | {"index": {"_index": "json", "_type": "json"}}, .'  | curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @-
I get the below error :  jq :error :syntax error , unexpected $end (unix shell quoting issues) at <top level> , line 1

Comment: Forget about the curl part. Try this "cat data.json | jq -c '. | {"index": {"_index": "json", "_type": "json"}}, .' " and see what output you get.

Comment: Hatim - You are a genius ! You made me think on what I was doing wrong , I retained the original format and ran for first 10 rows and it retrieved them successfully . I went head and the created the index as well.  What i am doing now is letting the command run for the 1000 odd rows that I have. It seems to be working on them slowly... will post and let u know...Appreciate all your help...

Comment: Hmmm , got an error after the command processed about 20K lines. The error is :      curl:(56) Recv failure : Connection reset by peer

Answer (score 0):

We're found it is necessary to specify `Content-Type` in the curl header; the suggested solution should be of the form:

`cat data.json | jq -c '. | {"index": {"_index": "json", "_type": "json"}}, .'  | 
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @-`